# PC won't post after Ubuntu 20.04 suspend

Tags: ubuntu, bios, post, suspend

After suspending my computer (Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) it seemed to shut down like normal. To wake it up, I tried pressing the power button, holding it down, and pressing keys on the keyboard. None of this did anything. As a last resort, I reset the CMOS. This had no affect.

If anyone knows what's going on, please let me know. My system’s motherboard is a Gigabyte X399 DESIGNARE EX (rev. 1.0).

Comment: Seems like a hardware issue, since you can't POST, much less get into BIOS. Power supply, perhaps? Loose connector?

Answer (score 0):

It's the power supply. It works for a second (I see 5 VDC on the USB port), then it stops working.